# How to draw a horizontal line in iTextSharp?

Tags: pdf, itext

I am creating a label that has an address on the left side and another address on the right side. I just want to create a line going down the middle to separate them. So the line needs to go all the way the length of the label (from 270 to 0)

I'm using `iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;`

so for example to show the address I use:

`cb.ShowTextAligned(int.Parse("50"), Company.Current.Address1, 270, 260, 270);`

The label is in landscape so the rotation is set to 270

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the high-level approach (using `document.Add()`), you use a [separator](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-building-blocks/separator-examples) to draw lines. It's very strange that you don't use the high-level approach. You claim that you use `showTextAligned()` because you need to work in landscape, but if you need to work in landscape, why not just define your page in landscape?

You are using the low-level approach (using `showTextAligned()`), so you have to use path-constructing and path-painting operators and operands. All these operators and operands are explained in [chapter 14 of my book](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-14). This link shows you the examples in Java, but if you scroll down, you'll find link to the `.cs` files.

If you have a `PdfContentByte` object `cb`, you can draw a line like this:

```
cb.MoveTo(x1, y1);
cb.LineTo(x2, y2);
cb.Stroke();
```

The values of `x1`, `y1` and `x2`, `y2` will depend on the coordinates you use to draw your text. In your case, you start writing text at coordinates `x = 270, y = 260`. I would define `x1` as `270` and `y1` as `260 - bf.GetWidthPoint(Company.Current.Address1)`.

Note that this parameter is wrong: `int.Parse("50")`. The first parameter of the `showTextAligned()` method should be a valid alignment. `50` is not a valid alignment value. You should replace it with `Element.ALIGN_LEFT`, `Element.ALIGN_RIGHT` or `Element.ALIGN_CENTER`. Obviously, you'll have to change the value of `y` if you change the alignment of your text.

Comment: The "separator" link is now dead.